# Access AWS services via IAM Role from long-running ASP.NET Core service

Tags: amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, aws-sdk

We're developing an ASP.NET Core web application that will be running on-premises in a customer environment, and that application needs access to certain resources in our AWS account. Because this crosses an organizational boundary, we're creating an IAM Role in our AWS account and granting the customer access to assume that role from their account.

I believe the way this must work is that the ASP.NET Core application has "permanent" credentials to the customer's AWS account, and then obtains temporary credentials for the IAM Role in our account in order to do work. However, the application needs to do most of its work in an `IHostedService`/`BackgroundService`, which is a singleton running for the duration of the application lifetime, so if we use the standard dependency injection, we'll have a single long-lived instance of a given AWS service client. Does anyone know if the AWS SDK has any ability to continually re-obtain temporary credentials for an IAM Role? If not, I assume we'll have to stop obtaining the service clients via DI and keep periodically re-creating them ourselves to refresh the credentials.

Answer (score 1):

> I believe the way this must work is that the ASP.NET Core application has "permanent" credentials to the customer's AWS account, and then obtains temporary credentials for the IAM Role in our account in order to do work. However, the application needs to do most of its work in an

From the usage document, SDK's AssumeRole function just make a request to get temporary credential as simple strings. You must input these credential yourself to any object/service client that you want to use that specific credential returned from AssumeRoleRequest

Which mean there is no built-in auto-refresh that suits your needs

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into [awsume](https://github.com/trek10inc/awsume) and the [AutoAwsume](https://github.com/trek10inc/awsume/wiki/AutoAwsume) plugin for it.

This is something that can be used to auto-refresh temporary IAM role credentials on a machine.

A similar solution was used by developers in a former project of mine as a security best practice to avoid giving out long-lived credentials.